# Updating chart.js with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, if-statement, chart.js

i'm trying to auto-update my chart js graph trough ajax , but my if statement always return the wrong awnser on the first iter , any idea why ? thank again. , tell me if you need anything more.

```js
setInterval(addData, 10000);
//setting the loop with time interval
function addData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get',
    url: "/hello-world/",
    success: function(response) {

      let labels = String(response.labels);
      let datas = response.datas;

      console.log('check', String(label.slice(-1)));
      console.log('in', labels);
      myChart.data.labels.slice(-2)[1]);


      if (labels == String(label.slice(-1))) {
        console.log('same content');
      } else {
        console.log('updating content', labels, 'to', String(label.slice(-1)));

        myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(datas);
        myChart.data.labels.push(labels);
        myChart.update();
        console.log('revisu', myChart.data.labels.slice(-2)[0], ' : ', myChart.data.labels.slice(-2)[1]);
        if (myChart.data.labels.slice(-2)[0] == myChart.data.labels.slice(-2)[1]) {
          console.log("something's wrong");

          myChart.data.labels.pop();
          myChart.data.datasets[0].data.pop();
          myChart.update();
        } else {

        };
        myChart.update();
      }
    }
  });


}
```

Comment: Firstly, you probably want to change this `url: 'get'` into this: `method: 'get'`.  Secondly, this statement doesn't seem to do anything and is faulty: `myChart.data.labels.slice(-2)[1]);`.  And finally, you are comparing labels that were retrieved in a server call.  Maybe include that server code...?

Comment: Update the question (and remove those comments).